# Tree Graph for bronchial structure from morphometric data

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have read other questions related to TreeGraph but couldn't find something similar to my problem.

I have a list of geometric properties of the bronchial tree, where each bronchus is represented by an ID as follows:

1: trachea

11: sub-trachea left

12: sub-trachea right

111: left bronchus of sub-trachea left

112: right bronchus of sub-trachea left

etc.

Looks straightforward, but I can't manage to create a TreeGraph from these data. I'have tried to sum up the values to create a path for TreeGraph but as several paths can have the same added values, this obviously doesn't work.

Here is my code (not optimized yet) for extraction and sorting of the data, struggling for the next steps.

```
dataraw=Import["http://mae.engr.ucdavis.edu/wexler/lungs/LF53-Raabe/id18.htm","Data"];
data=Transpose[dataraw];
(* Manipulation of data, formatting etc. *)
namesraw=Table[ToString[data[[j]][[1]]],{j,1,Length[dataraw[[1]]]}];
namestojoin=StringSplit [Table[namesraw[[i]]//ToLowerCase//StringTrim//StringSplit//StringJoin//StringTrim ,{i,1,Length[dataraw[[1]]]}],Except[WordCharacter]];
names=Table[StringJoin[namestojoin[[i]]],{i,1,Length[dataraw[[1]]]}]
dataok=Table[Table[ToExpression[StringTrim[ToString[data[[j]][[i]]]]],{i,2,Length[data[[1]]]} ],{j,1,Length[dataraw[[1]]]}];
listdata=Table[Symbol[names[[j]]]->Table[dataok[[j]][[i]],{i,1,Length[data[[1]]]-1}],{j,1,Length[dataraw[[1]]]}];
listbranchid=Sort@IntegerDigits@Table[listdata[[8]][[2]][[i]],{i,1,Length[listdata[[8]][[2]]] }];
(* Placing data in cluster aka generations *)
Table[clusterbranchid[j]={},{j,1,Max@Table[Length@listbranchid[[i]],{i,1,Length[listdata[[8]][[2]]]}]} ]; 
Table[Table
[If[Length[listbranchid[[i]]]==j,clusterbranchid[j]=Join[clusterbranchid [j],{listbranchid[[i]]}]],{j,1,Max@Table[Length@listbranchid[[i]],{i,1,Length[listdata[[8]][[2]]]}]}],{i,1,Length[listdata[[8]][[2]]]}];
(* Clusters visualisation *)
clusterbranchid[1]
clusterbranchid[2]
clusterbranchid[3]
clusterbranchid[4]
clusterbranchid[5]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ids = ToExpression@dataraw[[2 ;;, 8]];

G = TreeGraph[
  DirectedEdge @@@ Transpose[{
     Lookup[
      AssociationThread[ids -> Range[Length[ids]]],
      FromDigits@*Most@*IntegerDigits /@ Rest[ids]
      ],
     Range[2, Length[ids]]
     }],
  GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!